# How to solve declaration error due to repeated imports?

Tags: solidity

Let's say I have contract `Parent.sol` which has two imports:

```
import "./interfaces/IPair.sol";
import "./interfaces/IMasterChef.sol";
```

And both interfaces individually import `IERC20.sol`.

Well when I compile `Parent.sol`, I'll get declaration error due to repeateded import of `IERC20.sol`:

```
contracts/Parent.sol:7:1: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
import "./interfaces/IMasterChef.sol";
^------------------------------------^
contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol:4:1: The previous declaration is here:
interface IERC20 {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

Is there any way of solving this **without** flattening the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no namespacing or `import X as Y`, that would allow to use both interfaces with the same name.

---

If you don't want to merge the files, you can keep both but need to change the actual interface name of at least one them.

Example:

- `./interfaces/IPair.sol` imports `./Pair/IERC20.sol`, which defines `interface IERC20 {}`

  - change the definition to `interface IPairERC20 {}` and all occurrences that instantiate it (`new IERC20()` to `new IPairERC20()`)
- `./interfaces/IMasterChef.sol` imports `./MasterChef/IERC20.sol`, which defines `interface IERC20 {}`

  - change the definition to `interface IMasterChefERC20 {}` and all occurrences that instantiate it  (`new IERC20()` to `new IMasterChefERC20()`)

Comment: Thanks for this - shame there's no namespacing for it yet!